# A list of Android Permissions required for a certain Android API

Tags: android

Is there any way to find the list of all permissions that must be required for a certain Android API. Is it possible to do this by parsing the Android api?

Answer (score 0):

In this page you can check what API version have certain permission http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: there are many android apis like android.content, android.bluetooth etc. I want the list of all permissions that must be required for using an API say android.bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no full list available. But many APIs are explained in Android's [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). They'll also mention you that you'll need to add permission x to use the feature.

Why exactly do you want a full list of all permissions combined with the API that requires them?

Comment: For a given functionality of API xyz, I want to find similar functionality (if possible) in another APIs, that require lesser permissions or not at all.

Comment: Most of the time, you can't. You can't create a calendar event without the permission, you can't do an internet call without internet permission and so on.
Although, sometimes it is possible. For example, instead of adding the permission to make phone calls, you can simply open the Phone app with the phone number pre-entered. The user will need to press the 'call' button, but that shouldn't be that hard. Same for taking a picture(user needs to press the 'take picture' button). But, for most other permissions you can't workaround them.